# How to alter INFORMATION_SCHEMA or add triggers or foreign keys to it?

Tags: mysql, information-schema, mariadb

I'm trying to create some meta-data to extend mysql functionality but I can't create tables in the database INFORMATION_SCHEMA. I thought that I could just create another database and have my metadata in there but I need some foreign keys from my tables to some tables in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA DB. Nevertheless, I get errors when trying to create them. Then I thought I could create a trigger to get notified of changes but since triggers are associated to a table and I can't alter that database, I can't create triggers either.

Specifically I have some tables that references to `information_schema.schemata(schema_name)` and to `information_schema.schemata(columns)` and some others. I want to have those foreign key so I can use `ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE` or otherwise I'll have some rows in my tables referencing to nothing and I can't allow that.

I'm using mariaDB 5.5.30 which uses MySql 5.3.

Comment: I wonder if a materialized view on a view would work.  Than you could create indexes/keys off of the materialized view...

Answer (score 2):

INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables are actually views whose contents is automatically maintained by the MySQL server.

[The manual gives more information](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-schema.html):

> Inside INFORMATION_SCHEMA there are several read-only tables. They
>   are actually views, not base tables, so there are no files associated
>   with them, and you cannot set triggers on them. Also, there is no
>   database directory with that name.
>
> Although you can select INFORMATION_SCHEMA as the default database
>   with a USE statement, you can only read the contents of tables, not
>   perform INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE operations on them.

Comment: Thanks for that info. Do you know how can I "observe" when something change in those views?

Comment: I think you need to add triggers to the real tables you want to monitor, since INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables do not accept triggers.

Answer (score 1):

They are not really views but temporary tables, that's why you don't see folders.
show create view views;
ERROR 1347 (HY000): **'information_schema./tmp/#sql_2ac_0' is not VIEW**